# Как передать указатель в другую функцию с++?

Tags: c++, указатели

В С++ я полный ноль, начал изучать по нужде буквально сутки назад.
Есть проблема. Я создаю динамический массив. Потом мне нужно заполнить массив входными данными. Код заполнения массива решил вынести в отдельную функцию. Зачем - не спрашивайте. И тут проблема. Функция не видит указатель arr. Как заставить функцию его видеть? Есть какие-либо варианты, кроме передачи указателя аргументом в функцию?

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//СВАЛКА ПЕРЕМЕННЫХ

void delOZU();
void getArrData();

int* inData = new int(0);
int* arr_ptr = new int;

//-----------------

int main() {

    setlocale(0, "");

    cin >> *inData;

    cout << "Вы ввели число: " << *inData << endl;
    int* arr = new int[*inData];
    arr_ptr = arr;
    cout << "Массиву arr установлен лимит " + *inData << endl;
    cout << arr_ptr << endl;
    cout << "Введите значения массива по порядку от места 0 до места " + *inData << endl;
    getArrData();

    delOZU();

    return 0;
}

void getArrData() {
    int* i = new int(0);

    for (*i = 0; *i <= *inData; *i++) {
        cin >> *arr_ptr[*i];
    }

    delete i;
}

void delOZU() {
    cout << "\nУдаляем все указатели и освобождаем память!" << endl;
    delete inData;
}
```

Comment: Такое чвуство, что вы пытаетесь писать на джаве. Не нужно везде втыкать указатели и `new`. Единственное место, где вы использовали его более-менее по делу, это `int* arr = new int[...]`.

Comment: В таком случае вопрос. Когда рационально использовать указатели?

Comment: В вашей программе - вообще нигде. (Массив лучше заменить на `std::vector`.) В общем случае - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25705417/use-of-raw-pointers-in-modern-c-post-c11

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , не всегда лучше вектор, особенно  для новычков, которые еще не знакомы с контейнерами

Comment: Не понял. "Функция не видит указатель arr."? Какая функция и в каком месте? Я не вижу нигде в коде использования `arr`, кроме как в `main`. О каком "не видит" тогда идет речь?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Честно говоря, я бы сначала учил контейнерам, а потом указателям.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat,  то же самое, чтобы сначала учить литературу, а потом буквы.    Как понять контейнеры, если не имеешь представление о классах? Как иметь представление о классах, если не умеешь обращаться  к участкам памяти, не знаешь что такое указатель, как писать функции и для чего вообше они?...

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, точно ли вам нужно именно `inData+1` значение, но если считать, что да - то я бы написал такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//СВАЛКА ПЕРЕМЕННЫХ

void getArrData(int* arrptr, int size);


//-----------------

int main() {
    setlocale(0, "");
    int inData;
    cin >> inData;
    cout << "Вы ввели число: " << inData << endl;
    int* arr = new int[inData + 1];
    cout << "Массиву arr установлен лимит " << inData << endl;
    cout << "Введите значения массива по порядку от места 0 до места " <<
         inData << endl;
    getArrData(arr, inData);
    cout << "Значения в массиве:\n";

    for (int i = 0; i <= inData; i++) {
        cout << "Значение элемента " << i << " равно " << arr[i] << endl;
        }

    delete[]arr;
    return 0;
    }

void getArrData(int* arr_ptr, int inData) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= inData; i++) {
        cin >> arr_ptr[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Другими словами, объявленный указатель/переменную в одной функции, не будет видно в другой, если не передать ее аргументом?

Comment: @FBenz, или же должно быть объявлено до  определения функции(глобально)

Comment: Да, конечно. Локальная переменная видна только в пределах своей функции. При передаче в другую функцию по значению (как здесь) в этой другой функции видна копия локальной переменной.

Answer (score 2):

Тут несколько опечаток:

- Условие в цикле: `*i <= *inData` -> `*i < *inData` (иначе вы вылезаете на 1 элемент за границу массива).
- Изменение счетчика в цикле: `*i++` -> `(*i)++` (потому что у `++` приоритет выше).
- Доступ к элементу массива: `*arr_ptr[*i]` -> `arr_ptr[*i]`.
- Печать числа: `cout << "..." + *inData` -> `cout << "..." << *inData` (в С++ строки нельзя соединять с числами через `+`).

---

Но вообще - это несерьезно. Слишком много ненужных указателей и `new`.

Проще написать так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> GetArray()
{
    int size;
    std::cin >> size;

    std::vector<int> ret;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int x;
        std::cin >> x;
        ret.push_back(x);
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = GetArray();

    for (int x : vec)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Решать задачу по другому не всегда является ответом на вопрос, особенно в данном случаи(ИМХО)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Вот я поэтому и добавил в начало список проблем с кодом. Если ТС просто хочет заставить программу работать, этого ему хватит.